# Hide or redirect page on particular domain in DNN

Tags: url, iis, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a DNN site that has site bindings for 2 domains: `child.parent.com` and `child.com`.

`child.com` will be the main public facing site. `child.parent.com` exists as we have an SSL cert for `*.parent.com` so can secure the editing functions etc.

In DNN, can I disable the login page (`/login`) for the `parent.com` binding? Or redirect it to `https://child.parent.com/login`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN handles this and I managed what I wanted quite easily by doing the following:

1. Login as host and go *Host -> Site Settings*
2. Select the *Advanced Settings* tab and scroll down to SSL settings
3. Enable SSL (also needs to be enabled at host level) 
   and modify the SSL URL and Standard URL:

   - SSL Url: `child.parent.com`
   - Standard URL: `child.com`

For any page that is set to secure, e.g. the login page, this setting will redirect them to the secure site at `child.parent.com` if they are on `child.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the login **link** :Admin --> Advance Setting --> Security Settings Hide Login Control. This will result in no login link on your page. But when they are browsing to child.com/login they wil see your login page.

You must physically delete the page if you don't want them to sign in there.

About the redirect to a other login that is not possible.